# How can I push an object in an array of objects to an array within another array of object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a variable `parks` with the following:

```
let parks = [
  { id: 1, park_name: 'Average Park', review: [] },
  { id: 2, park_name: 'Better Park', review: [] },
  { id: 3, park_name: 'Cooler Park', review: [] },
  { id: 4, park_name: 'Dull Park', review: [] }
]
```

And another variable `review` with the following:

```
let review = [
  { id: 1, park_id: 1, comment: "It's an okay park. Seen better" },
  { id: 2, park_id: 1, comment: "Ehh, it's alright" },
  { id: 3, park_id: 2, comment: "It's pretty decent" },
  { id: 4, park_id: 3, comment: "Good not great" }
]
```

What I want to achieve is adding the `review` object to `parks.review` based on `park_id == parks.id`. Basically I want is this:

```
[
  { id: 1, park_name: 'Average Park', review: [{ id: 1, park_id: 1, comment: "It's an okay park. Seen better" },  { id: 2, park_id: 1, comment: "Ehh, it's alright" }] },
  { id: 2, park_name: 'Better Park', review: [{ id: 3, park_id: 2, comment: "It's pretty decent" }] },
  { id: 3, park_name: 'Cooler Park', review: [{ id: 4, park_id: 3, comment: "Good not great" }] },
  { id: 4, park_name: 'Dull Park', review: [] }
]
```

What is the best approach to take?

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: You have to loop through your `parks` array and, `forEach` park, `filter` the `review` array to select only the items where `park.id === item.park_id`; then you can copy the filtered array into your `park.review` using the spread operator or some other method.

Comment: Please take the time to read [ask] and the linked articles. The first section of that article is titled "Search, and research" and the tooltip for the downvote button starts with "This question does not show any research effort..." because a lot of questions (like this one) have already been answwered, and asking others to find those duplicate questions for you is disrespectful of their time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nested `for of` will be the easiest and straightforward way for scanning 2 arrays simultaneously and so something.

You can also do it in with a single loop and use [`_.find`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#find) or filter to make the code look more elegant

```js
let parks = [
  { id: 1, park_name: 'Average Park', review: [] },
  { id: 2, park_name: 'Better Park', review: [] },
  { id: 3, park_name: 'Cooler Park', review: [] },
  { id: 4, park_name: 'Dull Park', review: [] }
];
let reviews = [
  { id: 1, park_id: 1, comment: "It's an okay park. Seen better" },
  { id: 2, park_id: 1, comment: "Ehh, it's alright" },
  { id: 3, park_id: 2, comment: "It's pretty decent" },
  { id: 4, park_id: 3, comment: "Good not great" }
];

for(let park of parks) {
  for(let review of reviews) {
    if(park.id === review.park_id) {
      park.review.push(review);
    }
  }
}

console.log(parks);
```

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head I would do something like this:

```js
let parks = [
  { id: 1, park_name: "Average Park", review: [] },
  { id: 2, park_name: "Better Park", review: [] },
  { id: 3, park_name: "Cooler Park", review: [] },
  { id: 4, park_name: "Dull Park", review: [] },
];

let reviews = [
  { id: 1, park_id: 1, comment: "It's an okay park. Seen better" },
  { id: 2, park_id: 1, comment: "Ehh, it's alright" },
  { id: 3, park_id: 2, comment: "It's pretty decent" },
  { id: 4, park_id: 3, comment: "Good not great" },
];

const combined = parks.map((park) => ({
  ...park,
  review: reviews.filter((review) => review.park_id === park.id),
}));
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate both arrays only once.

Take `parks` to get a reference by `id` to the park and add all reviews to their referenced park.

```js
const
    parks = [{ id: 1, park_name: 'Average Park', review: [] }, { id: 2, park_name: 'Better Park', review: [] }, { id: 3, park_name: 'Cooler Park', review: [] }, { id: 4, park_name: 'Dull Park', review: [] }],
    review = [{ id: 1, park_id: 1, comment: "It's an okay park. Seen better" }, { id: 2, park_id: 1, comment: "Ehh, it's alright" }, { id: 3, park_id: 2, comment: "It's pretty decent" }, { id: 4, park_id: 3, comment: "Good not great" }],
    parkIds = Object.fromEntries(parks.map(o => [o.id, o]));

review.forEach(o => parkIds[o.park_id].review.push(o));

console.log(parks);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```